# How can I download an exposed mercurial directory?

Tags: scm

I have a client with an open .hg directory. For example, the URL http://example.com/.hg/dirstate shows a plain text config file. They have not enabled directory listing, so http://example.com/.hg/ gives a 403 Forbidden page.

I want to download the repository in order to obtain the source code. How can I download the contents of the .hg directory?

Comment: Not sure, but give this a shot "wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=2 -R index.html http://example.com/.hg/" Mind the auto-format removing "http://" from url in this comment.

Comment: Wget will try to get the links from the index, which in this case is just a 403. For getting the files, you'll need to run a filename bruteforcer, like DirBuster

Answer (score 1):

I have made [a tool](https://github.com/Sjord/sprengel) that performs some of the following steps:

- First, download the changelog and manifest files as described in the [repo structure documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Repository#Structure).
- Run `hg --debug manifest` to get a file list. Download the index for all these files.
- Fix the repo using the [convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption#Recovery_using_convert_extension)
- Run `hg update -C` to restore all files.

Now you have the source code.

Edit: more information in my [blog post about this](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2017/04/12/download-mercurial-hg-directory/).